# How to upload json file through jmeter?

Tags: json, jmeter, performance-testing

I have recorded my script to upload json file through Jmeter, but now I am facing the problem while uploading json file through jmeter which is on my local drive.

I am already done with following steps:

1. Either use full path to file, you're uploading, or copy it to JMeter's "bin" folder
2. Don't forget to tick Use `multipart/form-data` for HTTP POST box
3. Make sure you provide correct Parameter name and MIME Type

Getting exception in my response data:

```
{"Exception":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me works like this. [JSON example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6W44.png) May be Your server prefer some specific headers? E.g. content type and so on

Why you're using json file?
If you facing problems with generating random JSON data, here is a JSR223 preprocessor:

```java
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

def time = vars.get("stratup_time")
File myFile = File.createTempFile("upload-", "" );
// Generate Random length string and write to file

FileUtils.write(myFile, "{\"test\":\"$time\"", "UTF-8" )
// Store file name in variable.
vars.put( "filename", myFile.getCanonicalPath() )
```

And PostProcessor:

```java
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
// Delete file and do not throw error
FileUtils.deleteQuietly(new File( vars.get("filename")));
```

Comment: Thanks Guys, actually I got the answer, the thing is that my problem is fixed after recording the script from the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder, earlier it was not working because I was reordered my script from the BlazeMeter.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to record the file upload event **you need to copy your .json file to JMeter's "bin" folder**, this way HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder will be able to capture the request and generate necessary [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler. It will also populate the [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

More information: [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter)